# Reverse for 'google_login' not found. 'google_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth, google-signin

I Have a project and I want to use Google authentication for signup on my website.
This is my signup.html code:

```html
{% load socialaccount %}

<form class="site-form" action="{% url 'authentication:signup' %}" method="post">
    {{ form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>
        <a href="{% provider_login_url "google" %}">Login With Google</a>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </label>
</form>
```

and this is my `urls.py` file:

```py
    path('signup/', views.signup_view, name='signup'),
    path('google-login/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

and this is my view file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout

# Create your views here.
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(request, 'accounts:dashboard')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()    
    return render(request, './authentication/templates/login.html', {'form': form})

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect(request, 'accounts:dashboard')

def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)    
            return redirect(request, 'accounts:dashboard')
    return render(request, './signup.html', {'form': form})
```

but when I want to use from singup.html, this error raised:

```
Reverse for 'google_login' not found. 'google_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

and when I want to use from google-login, 404 not found displayed:

```
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
auth/ login/ [name='login']
auth/ logout/ [name='logout']
auth/ signup/ [name='signup']
auth/ google-login/ signup/ [name='account_signup']
auth/ google-login/ login/ [name='account_login']
auth/ google-login/ logout/ [name='account_logout']
auth/ google-login/ password/change/ [name='account_change_password']
auth/ google-login/ password/set/ [name='account_set_password']
auth/ google-login/ inactive/ [name='account_inactive']
auth/ google-login/ email/ [name='account_email']
auth/ google-login/ confirm-email/ [name='account_email_verification_sent']
auth/ google-login/ ^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$ [name='account_confirm_email']
auth/ google-login/ password/reset/ [name='account_reset_password']
auth/ google-login/ password/reset/done/ [name='account_reset_password_done']
auth/ google-login/ ^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key']
auth/ google-login/ password/reset/key/done/ [name='account_reset_password_from_key_done']
auth/ google-login/ social/
auth/ google-login/ google/
auth/ google-signup/
auth/ ^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, auth/google-login/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Comment: Would you provide the views.